# Geoserver ncWMS extension, GetTimeseries doesn't work

Tags: geoserver, wms, ncwms1.2

I am trying to use the [ncWMS extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/ncwms/index.html) with Geoserver 2.16. When I use the GetTimeseries endpoint I get an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://ncwms.weatherbell.com/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   
<ServiceException>
          java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.geoserver.wms.GetFeatureInfoRequest.setExcludeNodataResults(Z)V
    org.geoserver.wms.GetFeatureInfoRequest.setExcludeNodataResults(Z)V
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Request: getServiceInfo
08 Jan 21:29:20 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.geoserver.wms.GetFeatureInfoRequest.setExcludeNodataResults(Z)V
    at org.geoserver.wms.ncwms.NcWmsService.getTimeSeries(NcWmsService.java:201)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor248.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:879)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:265)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my request:

```
localhost:8080/geoserver/workspace/wms?SERVICE=WMS&\ 
VERSION=1.1.1&\ 
REQUEST=GetTimeSeries&\ 
FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&\ 
QUERY_LAYERS=workspace%3A2t&\ 
LAYERS=workspace%3A2t&\ 
INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fcsv&\ 
FEATURE_COUNT=50&\ 
X=50&\ 
Y=50&\ 
SRS=EPSG%3A4326&\ 
STYLES=&\ 
WIDTH=101&\ 
HEIGHT=101&\ 
BBOX=-102.89108276367188%2C30.399856567382812%2C-85.13717651367188%2C48.15376281738281&\ 
TIME=2019-11-14T21:00:00.000Z,2019-11-14T22:00:00.000Z,2019-11-14T23:00:00.000Z,2019-11-15T00:00:00.000Z,2019-11-15T01:00:00.000Z,2019-11-15T02:00:00.000Z,2019-11-15T03:00:00.000Z,2019-11-15T04:00:00.000Z,2019-11-15T05:00:00.000Z,2019-11-15T06:00:00.000Z,2019-11-15T07:00:00.000Z
```

I know those times are valid because I copy/pasted them from the `GetCapabilities` output.

This error makes no sense to me because `org.geoserver.wms.GetFeatureInfoRequest.setExcludeNodataResults` is in geoserver's core WMS code. (Though I don't know what (Z)V means).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you matched the plugin version to the geoserver version exactly? This sort of error usually indicates a version mismatch

Comment: @IanTurton I believe so. My geoserver version is 2.16.0 and I am using https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.16.x/community-latest/geoserver-2.16-SNAPSHOT-ncwms-plugin.zip

Comment: 2.16.x will match the nightly build (and maybe 2.16.1) 2.16.0 not so much

Comment: @IanTurton Are you sure about that? Look at the parent directory. All it contains is 2.14.x, 2.15.x, 2.16.x and master (which I assume is nightly). https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/

Comment: 2.16.x is built nightly too - community modules are not built for releases any longer - best to check github to see what may have changed, remember these are not designed for production use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have mismatched the plugin version and your GeoServer version - looking at the [issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9330) that added that function (found from the [PR](http://Looking%20at%20the%20PR%20https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/commit/99a6d10c527edb33df725503e2732c4423557eff%20seems%20to%20indicate%20it%20not%20intende)) it should work from 2.16.1.

If you want to stay on 2.16.0 then you need a plugin build [dated before 11th Sept 2019](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/commit/ab3109e96a9027050d32d0bfe31f940bea7af9d9) (and we seem to have no archive before the start of the year), or build it from the source code.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Look like you are right, of course. I'd just like to say that the versioning seems pretty confusing. There are docs for 2.17, but https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/ does not contain a 2.17 folder and neither does https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver. I can't find 2.16.1 at all, so I just went with a geoserver-master-latest-bin.zip (is that even a stable build?)

Comment: try http://geoserver.org/download/ for 2.16.1 - there are 3 versions of the docs dev, stable and maintenance which are currently 2.17, 2.16, 2.15 - pick the one that matches.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell me - does this extension support getting a time series for multiple parameters simultaneously? Perhaps through a coverage? It doesn't seem to.